# Get parent empty space

Tags: html, css

I have many elements with header of image with static height and some text below. Target is to get that `.outer` full height as the elements in the row with it. I need that text to get width of image and height to be full as it can be.
[This is what i have achieved at the moment](http://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/MwZmEp?editors=110).

CSS:

```
.outer {
     display: inline-block;
}
.inner {
    background: green;
    display: table-caption;
}
.inner>img{
  height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c322418/v322418480/131a7/c3HrxpJiYqY.jpg"/>
        <p>Useless Text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In short, you want to achieve equal height columns with image on top and space after text. Right?

Comment: @GoncharDenys, you are quite correct - i meant [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). sorry.

Comment: I have added it to codepen, link is on description.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the height using javacript?

Comment: It can be done with js with many ways, my problem is based on css, if it's not possible to do it with css then definitely i will do it with js.

Comment: @ManojKumar sorry, i really didn't notice your comment. Yeah, facts is image fixed height and container is inline-block for getting as much as possible items in the page row.

Comment: Are the columns always going to be the same width? Or rather, are the images always the same width?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVrGLO?editors=110

Comment: Columns have different widths, image have different widths.

Comment: @Rachel Gallen, you give fixed width, which is kinda wrong, but it the closest to answer.

Comment: @GoncharDenys i made an answer and a slight change

Comment: @GoncharDenys just as a sidenote i think its a better idea to put your images as background images it gives you more control. like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwLajr?editors=110

Comment: thanks for choosing my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the essential thing is vertical-align:top; I have given a fixed width but you can give width in percentage.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: green;
  width: 290px!important;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.inner>img {
  height: 200px;
}
.inner>p {
  width: inherit;
}
.inner>img,
.inner>p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c322418/v322418480/131a7/c3HrxpJiYqY.jpg" />
      <p>Useless Text. CSS is not an overly complex language. But even if you’ve been writing CSS for many years, you probably still come across new things — properties you’ve never used, values you’ve never considered, or specification details you never
        knew about. In my research, I come across new little tidbits all the time, so I thought I’d share some of them in this post. Admittedly, not everything in this post will have a ton of immediate practical value, but maybe you can mentally file
        some of these away for later use.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="inner">
      <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c322418/v322418480/131a7/c3HrxpJiYqY.jpg" />
      <p>This is an awesome text, but i want my element get height of left space up of my image.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="inner">
      <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c322418/v322418480/131a7/c3HrxpJiYqY.jpg" />
      <p>Useless Text. CSS is not an overly complex language. But even if you’ve been writing CSS for many years, you probably still come across new things — properties you’ve never used, values you’ve never considered, or specification details you never
        knew about. In my research, I come across new little tidbits all the time, so I thought I’d share some of them in this post. Admittedly, not everything in this post will have a ton of immediate practical value, but maybe you can mentally file
        some of these away for later use.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your code point me to add `vertical align: top;` on `inline-block` elements, which kinda fix my problem. Your code have the issue of fixed width which is not what we need. http://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/BNMBeo?editors=110 Here is the solution. One more thing can help my problem, that green field to be till the end, but even without it it's ok.

Comment: if green field is to the end just set a background color in the outer div

Comment: outer don't get height of row. I could make it's background same with body background but shadows would brake it down.

Comment: also about width, it should be auto get from image and set to text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85114/discussion-between-gonchar-denys-and-rachel-gallen).

Answer (score 2):

I have made some adjustments to your code, I have added a class `table-div` and a class `table-row` and wrapped those `div.outer` in `div.table-div` and `div.table-row`. You can see it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XboROq?editors=110. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: You have removed `display: inline-block`, which is important for moving box down when screen is smaller. On large screen that is what i need.

Comment: Why is `display: inline-block;` important?

Comment: For example in smaller widths i need 2 `.outer` up and 1 down. On Larger screen i need 8 `.outer` etc.

Comment: I guess fixed height is out of discussion. :)

Comment: We have fixed image height, if we could use fixed text height and lose text there wont be a reason this post to exists :)